# How to send API key of custom name with file_get_contents?

Tags: php, authorization

The API I am trying to connect to uses an API key labelled `x-openaip-client-id`.

```
<?php

$countryCode = "DE";
$token = "fsdfdsf";


$url = "https://api.core.openaip.net/api/airspaces?type=4&country=" . $countryCode;
$options = array('http' => array(
    'method'  => 'GET',
    'header' => 'Authorization: x-openaip-client-id '.$token
));

$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$raw = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);


$array = json_decode($raw);

print("<pre>".print_r($array,true)."</pre>");

?>
```

Is there a way to do this with `file_get_contents()`?

Or must I resort to curl or similar component?

Documentation is at https://docs.openaip.net

Comment: What specific issue are you having with the current code? I'm guessing the header should perhaps be just `'header' => 'x-openaip-client-id: '.$token` ...normally an API key and an auth token are not the same thing. Of course if we could get a link to the API's documentation, we'd know for sure. P.S. file_get_contents can do standard stuff like send request headers just as easily as cURL can

Comment: You can absolutely do so. Make sure openssl is activated. Take a look in the error logs.

Comment: Documentation is at https://docs.openaip.net/

Comment: @ADyson you are right, good catch =) thanks. Want to post as answer?

Comment: You might also want to set additional SSL related parameters for the context to mitigate MITM attacks etc

Comment: I was wondering about that - the url is https, but does this part "$options = array('http' =>" mean it's actually not using SSL? Or what params were you suggesting?

Comment: The `http` portion of the `$options` is OK - you can add another key, at same level as http called `ssl` which holds an array of config parameters. Briefly, like: `'ssl'=>array( 'cafile' => '/path/to/your/cacert.pem', 'verify_peer' => true, 'verify_peer_name' => 2 )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As confirmed by the documentation, the header should be just

```
'header' => 'x-openaip-client-id: '.$token
```